# How to avoid shadow-root in MathJax?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I want to access the SVG code created by `MathJax` via javascript. Apparently, `MathJax` put the SVG `<path>` under `shadow-root`, which is not directly accessible by `javascript`. Here is a picture of the elements given by Chrome

[image]

If I get the `<svg>` element by any javascript method, the `<path>` children will not be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid `shadow-root`. It is not put there by MathJax renderer. It is because of the `use` tag.
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use):

> The `<use>` element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else.

So MathJax creates svg pathes and gives them ids and reuses them. Say the letter `a` is rendered into svg, and MathJax stores it in the svg with an id and **use** it when the letter `a` is needed to be rendered.

---

Below example from MDN speaks better.

```html
<svg width="80" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .classA {
      fill: red;
    }
  </style> 
  <defs>
    <g id="Port">
      <circle style="fill: inherit;" r="10"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
 
  <text y="15">black</text>
  <use x="50" y="10" href="#Port" />
  <text y="35">red</text>
  <use x="50" y="30" href="#Port" class="classA"/>
  <text y="55">blue</text>
  <use x="50" y="50" href="#Port" style="fill: blue;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It might be useful to add that, MathJax can be configured to not use `<use>` elements by setting `useFontCache` to `false` in the SVG output configuration, http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/SVG.html

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger thanks for information. Great 